# Is it possible to construct an action of an $E_\infty$ operad on $BU$ that respects filtration by $BU(n)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, operads

It is well known that $BU$ is an infinite loop space, and as such it has an action of an $E_\infty$ operad. An explicit construction of such an action is given, for example, in an answer to  [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94295/infinite-loop-space-structure-of-bu) . My question is whether it is possible to construct an action that respects the filtration of $BU$ by $BU(n)$.

Let me spell out the question more explicitly: is it possible to construct a filtered space $X_1 \subset X_2 \subset \cdots X$ such that for each $n$ $X_n\simeq BU(n)$, and there is an action of an $E_\infty$ operad $P$ on $X$ such that operad structure maps like $$P(i)\times X^i\to X$$ restrict to maps
$$P(i)\times X_{n_1}\times\cdots \times X_{n_i}\to X_{n_1+\cdots+ n_i}$$

Comment: Doesn't the multiplicative structure of algebraic K-theory respect the filtration? In this case, shouldn't a similar product (as the one defined by Loday) work?

Comment: I believe the multiplicative structure on $K$-theory is induced by tensor products which changes the rank.

Comment: What happens if you filter the topological category of complex vector spaces by rank and apply Segal's machine? I guess it's not so obvious what the $X_n$'s end up being in this case, though...

Comment: @DylanWilson Whenever I try any such approach, I get an $E_\infty$ operad acting on $\coprod BU(n)$. This action does respect the obvious filtration. It makes $\coprod BU(n)$ into a homotopy commutative monoid, whose group completion is ${\mathbb Z}\times BU$. However, I am really interested in obtaining a filtered $E_\infty$ structure on $BU$.

Comment: Group-completion takes E_infty algebras to E_infty algebras, so you get some filtration on $\mathbb{Z} \times BU$ (better: an E_infty object in filtered spaces). Are we worried about the $\mathbb{Z}$ or are we worried about identifying the pieces of the filtration?

Comment: @DylanWilson The filtration of $\coprod BU(n)$ is by subspaces, but not by $E_\infty$ subalgebras. So I don't see how group completion gives me a filtration of ${\mathbb Z}\times BU$. To illustrate the point: the monoid of natural numbers has a natural filtration by numbers up to $n$. Does it induce a natural filtration of the integers?

Comment: @GregoryArone: I think it does! In that case X_n is the set of integers $\le n$, and addition respects the filtration. I wasn't claiming that the filtration was of $E_{\infty}$-subalgebras, I was claiming that the whole object was an $E_{\infty}$-object in filtered spaces- just like a filtered algebra is different than an algebra filtered by subalgebras.

Comment: @DylanWilson I am still not sure what is the group completion of an $E_\infty$ object in filtered spaces. As far as I can tell, this approach can only give me a rather trivial filtration of ${\mathbb Z}\times BU$, where $X_n$ is something like the union of all components indexed by numbers $\le n$. But I will be happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: Yeah as I said, I'm not so sure what the X_n's are. The hope is that they look like $\mathbb{Z}_{\le n} \times BU(n)$... I would need to figure out group completion on the category of associative monoid objects in filtered spaces, and I dunno what that looks like off the top of my head. You might be right that this ends up giving a silly filtration...

Comment: I'm perplexed. We now have two conflicting answers, and both are so beautiful I refuse to disbelieve either one or other. Moreover you accepted one of the answers, so seemingly you find it settled. I believe in such situation it would be better to clarify the status of the second answer. If there is a flaw, imo it must be clearly indicated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such filtration.

At first, this looks very similar (but not as strong as) asking for a map of $E_\infty$ spaces $\coprod BU(n) \to BU$ which would become a splitting map $ku \to bu$ of spectra. We know that doesn't happen, because there's a nontrivial $k$-invariant.

We can look more carefully at how this $k$-invariant works and it leads us to a method to give an actual contradiction. The $k$-invariant is detected by the fact that the generator $1_{ku}$ of $\pi_0 ku$ is annihilated by the Hopf element $\eta$, and the Toda bracket $\langle 2, \eta, 1_{ku}\rangle$ contains the Bott element $\beta$ and does not contain zero. This is spelled out in the following way on the level of $E_\infty$ spaces. Suppose $X$ is an $E_\infty$ space with multiplication $\smile$ and associated spectrum $KX$, and let $\alpha \in \pi_0(X)$ have image $[\alpha] \in \pi_0(KX)$. Up to translating path components, the element $\eta[\alpha] \in \pi_1(KX)$ lifts (up to changing path components) to the element $\alpha \smile_1 \alpha \in \pi_1(X, \alpha \smile \alpha)$. We can find a canonical nullhomotopy of the path composite of $\alpha \smile_1 \alpha$ with itself, expressing the identity $2 \eta [\alpha] = 0$; if we also have a nullhomotopy of $\alpha \smile_1 \alpha$, then we can use this to construct a representative for the bracket. If you carry this out for the basepoint of $BU(1)$ using the standard map $E\Sigma_2 \times_{\Sigma_2} BU(1)^2 \to BU(2)$, you find that you get the generator of $\pi_2 BU(2) = \Bbb Z$. However, in $bu$ this would mean that there was a bracket $\langle 2,\eta, 0\rangle$ which did not contain zero; that would be bad.

---

Of course, it turns out to be a lot easier to appeal to some machinery. Kochman calculated the Dyer-Lashof operations on $H_* BU = \Bbb F_2[x_1, x_2, \dots]$. His calculations show, for example, that $Q^4 x_1 = x_1^3 + x_1 x_2 + x_3$. As a result, the map $H_6 (E\Sigma_2 \times_{\Sigma_2} BU(1)^2) \to H_6(BU)$ is surjective, but the map $H_6(BU(2)) \to BU$ is not (it is missing $x_1^3$). This means that our operad structure map $P(2) \times X_1 \times X_1 \to X$ could never land in a subobject $X_2$ as you want. (This assumes that I've read and understood correctly in calculating the operations.)

(I actually find Priddy's method for calculating the Dyer-Lashof operations here a little easier than trying to understand Kochman's algorithm: Priddy calculates the Dyer-Lashof operations on $H_*(\coprod BU(n)) = \Bbb F_2[a_0,a_1,\dots]$ and then you can deduce the operations on the generators $x_i = a_i a_0^{-1}$ of $H_* BU$ by the Cartan formula. The inverse screws up the property of preserving homogeneous degree and it's what's messing us up here.)

Comment: This is great! Stupid question: what's the difference between ku and bu?

Comment: @Dylan I'm using $ku$ for the connective complex K-theory spectrum and $bu$ for its $0$-connected cover, which have infinite loop spaces $\Bbb Z \times BU$ and $BU$ respectively. (This is not consistent with the older literature, which uses $bu$ for the former.)

Comment: Am I correct in interpreting the final argument as a proof that this filtration is not even E_2? (Since it looks like you only need Q^4 on a degree 2 class).

Comment: Whoops, I guess it’s an E_3 operation. Never mind. I wonder if it’s possible to modify the first argument to rule out an E_2 filtration. (This is all motivated from conversations with Jeremy Hahn on his recent preprint with Allen Yuan. They show that the corresponding filtration on \OmegaSU(n) from Mitchell is A_infty, and ask whether it is E_2. I gather that the expectation is that it isn’t, but it’s stated as a question.)

Comment: @DylanWilson Yeah, since everything is in even degree you're kind of hosed for interesting E_2-algebra operations, because both $Q_1(-)$ and $[-,-]$ take even-degree classes to odd ones.

Comment: Right, but what about the first argument? I'm trying to figure out what that uses... Would it work any time you have an E_2 gadget with vanishing bracket? The E_2 piece would buy you the $\cup_1$ and is it the vanishing bracket that gets you the nullhomotopy of $\alpha \cup_1 \alpha$? Or is it something else? Because if this filtration were $E_2$ then, as you say, the bracket would also vanish by evenness.

Comment: @DylanWilson Yeah, you need the E_3-structure to get the homotopy of the cup-square with itself. In terms of $\infty$-categories the E_2-structure makes the groupoid associated to $BU$ into a braided-monoidal groupoid and the square of the twist map doesn't have a trivialization until you add in the E_3-structure. Or said yet another way, if we take 2-fold classifying spaces then I'm thinking about $\eta$ times an element in $\pi_2$, and $2\eta \in \pi_3(S^2)$ isn't trivial yet.

Comment: My guess is that if you want to get something, you probably need to mix in some interaction with the Steenrod operations.

Answer (score 3):

Fix your favourite small infinite vector space $V$; note that the space of (ordered) decompositions $f:V \simeq \bigoplus_1^k V$ is contractible, so the space of *sets* of inclusions  $\{ f_j | j = 1,...,k\}$ (i.e., forgetting the order) is a model of $B \mathfrak{S}_k$.  To such a set of inclusions $I$ and a choice of suspaces $W_j \subset V$ indexed by $I$, write $\bigoplus_I W_j = \sum f_j W_j$.

Our model of $BU$ will be the subspaces of $V$ of finite corank, and the filtration $BU_n$ will be the subspaces specifically of corank at-most-$n$.

**Claim**: $BU_n$ is a model of $\mathbf{B}U(n)$.

**Idea**: I'll describe a blow-up $ X \to BU_n \backslash BU_{n-2}$ and argue both equivalences $X \simeq BU_n \backslash BU_{n-1}$ and $X \simeq BU_n\backslash BU_{n-2}$.

Given a space $W \lt V$ of corank $n-1$ the fiber of the blowup over $W$ consists of all choices of a basis $b :\mathbb{C}[x]\simeq W$ (contractible choice!); let $X$ be the mapping cylinder of the map assigning to $(W;b)$ the subspace $b(x\mathbb{C}[x])$; extend the cylinder map to $p : X \to BU_n\backslash BU_{n-2}$ by $(W;b,t) \mapsto b\left((1-t + tx)\mathbb{C}[x]\right)$

The mapping cylinder of course deformation retracts to its base, $BU_n \backslash BU_{n-1}$; on the other hand, the homotopy specified by $s \mapsto t \mapsto ts$ interpolates $p$ and the map forgetting both $t$ and $b$; which map has contractible (set-theoretic) fibers.

Comment: I am having difficulties with a couple of steps here. 1. As far as I understand, the space of ordered decompositions is the space of isomorphisms Iso$(V^k, V)$. If so, it is homeomorphic to an infinite unitary group and I don't see why it is contractible. 2. It seems to me that $BU_n$ is the space of subspaces of $V$ of corank **exactly** $n$, while spaces of corank at most $n$ give you the disjoint union of $BU(i)$ from $1$ to $n$. BTW, I would be really happy to have an answer to this question. So if I am misunderstanding, and someone can explain, I will be grateful.

Comment: Corank is not continuous; one can linearly homotopify Hilbert's Hotel, but one pays for it by leaving the space of Fredholm operators; more importantly, Iso(V,V) is not the stable general linear group; stable U is the operators $g \in Iso(V,V)$ with $g-1$ of finite rank.

Comment: You are right about the group of isomorphisms. Do you have a reference for the model of $BU_n$ as the space of subspaces of corank at most $n$? Thank you!

Comment: Reference, no. Idea of an argument now supplied.

Comment: I can't make any sense of the Idea. If I understand the definition of $BU_n$, at least set-theoretically, then $BU_{n-1}$ is contained in $BU_{n}$ (good).  The space   $BU_n\setminus BU_{n-1}$ is then the complement, I guess?  How does studying these complements tell us anything about the homotopy type of $BU_n$?

Comment: What I was trying to get at is that including BU_small or not shouldn't affect the homotopy type of the thing... and I'm ... at the moment I'm a bit bamboozled by the calculations Tyler describes above. If they're right AND apropos, I'm left wondering what on earth it is I have constructed, because it's certainly Not Nothing.  (e.g., each BU_n as described is connected, et.c. ...).

Comment: I guess the point is supposed to be that the space of subspaces of corank exactly n (which you say is homotopy equivalent to X) models BU(n) because one can build a vector bundle over it where the fibers are V/W?  And they you're trying to argue that when you include the subspaces of smaller rank, you're not changing the homotopy type.  I guess I see better the strategy now.

Comment: Right... except something, evidently, goes wrong.

Comment: @Jesse I've been trying to understand your answer to resolve this discrepancy. I guess what I'm having trouble with most is trying to understand the topology on the space BU_n of subspaces of corank at most n. My first naive try was that it was a quotient space: every subspace W < V of corank at most n is the kernel of a function $f:V \to \Bbb C^n$, and two functions f,f' have the same kernel if and only if there is an element g in $GL_n(\Bbb C)$ so that gf = f'.

Comment: So my first attempt was to start with the space of linear transformations $\Bbb C^\infty \to \Bbb C^n$ (the set of $n \times \infty$ matrices) and take the quotient space by the action of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$. When I do that, though, I find that the point represented by the infinite zero matrix is dense in the resulting space (for any matrix A, $t I \cdot A$ gives a path of matrices that represent the same subspace but converge to 0). But reading your answer it doesn't look like I'm using the same topology that you are and so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @TylerLawson Cannot one use the union topology on $GL_{n+N}(\mathbb C)/(GL_N(\mathbb C)\times GL_n(\mathbb C))$? That is, view finite-dimensional Grassmanians as spaces of quotient spaces and pass to the limit?

Comment: ...or perhaps one could modify the Pressley-Segal model - the Grassmanian of subspaces of a polarized Hilbert space. They have all kinds of stratifications and cell decompositions of it which might be used

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I was indeed trying to modify that construction to fit the spec. That union you describe (or something like it) tells you about subspaces of $\Bbb C^\infty$ which are of exact corank n and which, for some $k$, contain all elements $(z_i)_{i \geq 0}$ such that $z_i = 0$ when $i < k$. It doesn't e.g. describe the subspace $\{(z_i) | \sum z_i = 0\}$.

Comment: So, here's how to perturb an injection $T : W \to V$: write $V=T W \oplus X$; consider any map $l : W \to X $ and all the injections $Z:W \to W$ as close to (or as far from) $1$ as you like; then $S = l + T Z : W \to V $ is another injection which still has $S W \cap X =0$, though $SW + X$ may not be all of $V$ anymore.  This gives a neighborhood of injections about some nonsurjective, all missing some (space of) vectors; **corollary**: the automorphisms of $V$ are a closed set of injections.

Comment: @TylerLawson Acknowledged. Still, it looks like close to something that is really needed. I mean, if one works with (some to be precisely described) infinite dimensional bundles together with the trivialization of a finite codimension quotient/subbundle, then indeed one should expect that in the corresponding classifying space, one has subspaces which are "almost standard" in some sense. Sorry for this incoherent comment.

Answer (score 3):

let me give a possibly helpful "answer" by ancient history.   Since I don't actually have an answer, these should be comments, but they
are too long for that.  In Section 1 of Chapter I of  "$E_{\infty}$ ring spaces and $E_{\infty}$ ring spectra", http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/e_infty.pdf, I gave a systematic account of the action of the linear isometries operad $\mathcal{L}$ on infinite homogeneous spaces  $G/\prod_{1\leq i \leq n} G_i)$  of classical groups.  It includes all of the classical groups and, via the usual Grassmannians, all of their classifying spaces.   By construction, all of these are colimits related to, but not at all the same as, the one given by the natural filtration you ask about.  They are all given by functors  $T$ defined on a graded category of finite dimensional (real) inner product spaces, the grading given by dimension; see Definitions 1.6 and 1.8, op cit. So for the real analogue of your question $T$ would send $V$ to  $O(V\oplus V)/O(V)\times O(V)$.  The $\mathcal{L}$-space associated to $T$ is the colimit $T(\mathbf{R}^{\infty})$ of the $T(V)$.   This is not what you ask for, but it is the most geometric action in sight.  The construction there was tailored towards proving that all of the Bott maps are $E_{\infty}$ maps, and there might be some alternative packaging that does what you want.  You mention the quite different operad acting on $\coprod BU(n)$, which by construction from the permutative category $\coprod U(n)$ behaves as you wish before group completion.  Perhaps a comparison between these two different operad actions might be relevant, and I gave that in "The spectra associated to $\mathcal{I}$-monoids", http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/24.pdf.

Several comments refer to the multiplicative structure $\otimes$ rather than to the additive structure $\oplus$ you are implicitly asking about.
The bipermutative category $\coprod BU(n)$ gives rise to an $E_{\infty}$ ring space structure, but that would lead to a different (and slightly
ill-posed) question with your sum of the $n_i's$ replaced by their product.