# Is it possible to classify finite dimensional vector bundles in terms of Fredholm operators?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, index-theory

Let ${\mathcal K}$ be the space of Fredholm operators on a Hilbert space. It is well known that ${\mathcal K}$ represents $K$-theory. Let ${\mathcal K}_0$ be the path component of ${\mathcal K}$ of operators of index zero. Then ${\mathcal K}_0$ is a model for the space that algebraic topologists usually call $BU$ - the classifying space of the infinite unitary group.

My question is: is it possible to realise the filtration of $BU$ by the subspaces $BU(n)$ in terms of Fredholm operators?

An obvious idea is to consider the subspace of ${\mathcal K}_0$ consisting of operators whose kernel/cokernel has rank at most $n$. Is this space weakly homotopy equivalent to $BU(n)$?

Hopefully this question is interesting enough on its own (I am prepared to find out that it is stupid). My motivation is to understand better  [Jesse McKeown's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248302/is-it-possible-to-construct-an-action-of-an-e-infty-operad-on-bu-that-respe)  to my previous question. This is my attempt to understand the statement that the space of subspaces of a Hilbert space of corank at most $n$ is a model for $BU(n)$. If there are other ways to make it precise, I would be very interested in learning about it.

**EDIT:** I think that  [Tyler Lawson's negative answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248302/is-it-possible-to-construct-an-action-of-an-e-infty-operad-on-bu-that-respe/248518#248518)  to the previous question makes it very likely that the answer to this question is negative as well.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{K}_k^l$ be the space of index $k$ Fredholm operators whose kernel is $l$ dimensional. There is a fiber sequence $GL(\mathbb{H})\rightarrow \mathcal{K}_k^l\rightarrow BU(l)\times BU(k-l)$ where the right map is mapping an operator to the kernel times the cokernel. It follows that $\mathcal{K}_k^l$ is homotopy equivalent to $BU(l)\times BU(k-l)$. I do not now what happens when one takes the union over $l\leq l_0$.

Comment: Being the Jesse mentioned, I'm also keen to understand what my spaces actually are, and well open to the possibility that they're not BU(n)s.

Comment: @JesseC.McKeown: Just a ping

Answer (score 4):

The problem with my remark from a couple of years ago is that the cokernel can also "move around". Let us therefore fix this.

Let $W\subset \mathbb{H}$ be a finite, say $l$, dimensional subspace of a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space. I assume it is known that the space of $l$ dimensional subspaces of the Hilbert space is a model for $BU(l)$.

Let $\mathcal{O}^W=\{A\in \mathcal{K}_0\,|\, A(\mathbb{H})+W=\mathbb H\}$ be the space of Fredholm operators whose image is transverse to $W$. The space $\mathcal{O}^W$ is an open subspace of the space of Fredholm operators. There is a map $\mathcal{O}^W\rightarrow BU(l)$, that maps an operator $A$ to the subspace $A^{-1}(W)$. Note that the operator $A$ sends $A^{-1}(W)^\perp$ isomorphically to $W^\perp$. There are $GL(A^{-1}(W)^\perp,W^\perp)$ many such choices to do this. This suggest that 
$$
GL(\mathbb H)\rightarrow \mathcal O^W\rightarrow BU(l)
$$
is a fiber bundle. But by Kuiper's theorem $GL(\mathbb H)$ is contractible, so we have the required (weak) homotopy equivalence.

Now how does this fit into a grander story? You can take a sequence of finite dimensional $W_i$ that include in each other and $\mathbb{H}=\overline{\bigcup W_i}$. For example one can take $W_i$ to be the span of the first $i$ vectors in a basis of $\mathbb H$. Let us assume this. Then $\mathcal O^{W_i}\subset \mathcal O^{W_{j}}$ if $i\leq j$. This is the analogue of $BU(i)\subset BU(j)$. And $\bigcup _i \mathcal O^{W_i}=\mathcal K_0$.

I should credit Dan Freed's lecture notes https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2015/index.html.